# Difference between dba_SEGMENTS and dba_data_files

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Shouldn't these two queries give the same result? First is a sum of all segments while other is the sum of all data files. They are giving different results for me.
While the first one gives me 149522MB, the other gives 214973.34 MB

```
select sum(bytes)/1024/1024 MB from dba_segments;

select sum(bytes)/1024/1024 MB from dba_data_files;
```

Comment: Do both Oracle and MySQL have dba_segments and dba_data_files?

Comment: I think only Oracle has. Not sure. Why?

Comment: Since you have both Oracle and MySQL tags...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle uses "logical" und "physical" structures to store the data. For this case: The extents of a segment can be stored in different datafiles, so just summing up can work but must not work see here:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/logical.htm#CNCPT301

Plus: Oracle has a "High Water Mark" so even if your segment size sinks, your extends and datafiles don't shrink beneath the size of your HWM automatically, i. e. see here:

http://www.dbspecialists.com/resizing-datafiles-and-understanding-the-high-water-mark/

Comment: Thanx a lot. The first link explained me well :)